# Java generic list in inheritance cause to unchecked call to add(e)

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Having these class hierarchy causes to 'unchecked call to add(e)...'

```
public abstract class A{
    protected List<MyField> fields;
}

public abstract class B extends A{

}

public class foo extends B{

    public void doSomething(){
            this.fields.add(new MyField()); 
      }
}
```

If I store the fields list in class B the warning disappear.
Can someone explain that?
thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between `MyFields` and `myObject`?

Comment: @AndyTurner - Edited.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure that `A` isn't generic (which you omitted for simplicity)?

Comment: `this.fields.add(new MyField());` is not in any methods. Put it into a method you want.

Comment: @AndyTurner-  Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: This code doesn’t give me any warning.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?